# Regex, find first - Python

Tags: python, regex, string

```
i="<wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x2887828> >]], [[[41, 183], 'Button', <wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x28879d0> >]]]"

m = re.findall("<wx.(.*)> >", i)
```

will give me

```
["<wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x2887828> >]], [[[41, 183], 'Button', <wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x28879d0> >"]
```

However I want it to give me,

```
["<wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x2887828> >","<wx._controls.Button; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxButton *' at 0x28879d0> >"]
```

The regex is searching all the way until the end, I would like to take all the parts out that match the regex, Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: have you tried (.*?) instead of (.*)
it will do a lazy search

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `*` operator is greedy by default. You can change this by adding a `?` after it. Also remember to quote the literal dot.

I also made the group non-matching, otherwise you wouldn't get the desired output (this seems to be a problem with your original code as well):

```
re.findall(r"<wx\.(?:.*?)> >", i)
```

Another possiblity would be the following (assuming that exactly one `<` character comes before the first `>`), which is faster than the version with the lazy `*` operator:

```
re.findall(r"<wx\.[^<]*<[^<]*> >", i)
```